# husky A200 setup

Tags: ros, clearpath, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to set up a Husky a200 in my school research lab. I tried to followed the instruction on how to set it up, but I got confused on the order of instructions.

Following [this website](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Husky), In step 1, I went through the [ROS and catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) beginner tutorials by downloading Ubuntu 16.04 and kinetic distribution. Then, I tried to follow the [Install and Configure Husky Software](http://wiki.ros.org/husky_bringup/Tutorials/Install%20Husky%20Software) link to setup the Husky, and this is where I get confused.

In the link, it told me to install Indigo Husky ISO image file onto my robot PC, since I already have ubuntu 16.04 and ROS installed from doing the tutorial, does this mean, I need to wipe it and install the Indigo Husky ISO image file instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288860/husky-a200-setup/) by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, that ISO image is a disk image that will overwrite all other data. You may want to backup what you have done into another image before installing the Husky ISO. Then, if plan B doesn't work, you may revert to plan A. I believe the ISO image has ROS Indigo and Ubuntu Trusty.

---

Originally posted by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) with karma: 299 on 2018-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-04-20**:
Thank you fam!

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-05-20**:
hello, what if I have an UR5 manipulator attached to my husky? it seems like the ISO image provided from the husky website is only for just the husky platform

- http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/husky/InstallHuskySoftware.html#installing-husky-software

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2018-05-20**:
The UR5 software should be installed after the Husky software is functional. You may download it here:
https://www.universal-robots.com/support/
(As far as I know.)